# How can I secure a table that is hanging off the wall via four screws (2 on each side) from slipping away?

Tags: hanging

I have just installed a table that sits on four screws.

Two of the screws are a little tilted and I want to avoid having the table slip off them.

If I could redo this, I would probably use some fasteners but I don't want to rescrew those if I can.

Is there a screw plate or a wire that I could wrap around the ends of the screw to reduce the chances of the table slipping off?

Thanks!!

[image: Image of table lying on the ground below its screws]

Comment: How about a picture of the table.

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: What are the screws fastened to?  We *really* need a full picture or detailed drawing

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added a picture of the table now. Sorry about the missing context.

Comment: The table won't "slip off of a screw" just because the screw isn't perfectly straight into the wood. It might not look as pretty as you'd like, but the threads will hold just fine. Gravity will do the work of keeping the wood on the metal bracket, and the 4 screws will work together to keep the wood on the brackets, no matter their angle.

Answer (score 2):

The 4 screws you installed will hold the desktop to those metal supports. The screws should be long enough to pentetrate at least 3/4 in.
The real issue is how are you mounting/attaching the support to the wall.  The metal support should be mounted on the wall first at the height you want snd leveled.  You need to located where the studs are behind the drywall.  Studs are normally 16" on center. So find the two studs, 48 in. apart.  Use 5/16- 2 1/2" long lag bolts to screw the support to the wall.  After the support are installed, place desktop on support and rescrew the desktop to the support.  Odds are that you will have to s crew in at new holes.  Not the one you are using now.

Comment: Note the screw holes on the bracket are slotted, this will allow you to fine tune the level if you're off a bit after you drill the holes. Once level tighten the lag bolts.